# Controller must either provide JsonResult or redirect to view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, extjs

I have an ExtJs formpanel with standardSubmit: false. On submit, the controller will validate the formdata since some validation will take place on the server (for example a check if the name is unique). If the provided entity is invalid, a JsonResult is sent to the client to notify the user which fields are invalid. That works perfectly. If the entity is valid, it will be stored in the database and the controller must redirect the user to a specific view.

The result is that the HTML provided by the view is sent to the client which expects a JSON-response. Obviously, this does not work.

```
public override ActionResult Create(FormCollection formCollection)
    {
        Models.Relatie relatie = Repository.CreateNew();
        SetFormValues(relatie, formCollection);

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _relatieService.CreateRelation(relatie);
            ViewResult view = View("Index");
            return view; //pumps html while client expects JSON
        }
        else
        {
            JsonResult json = Json(new { success = false, errors = ModelState.ToDictionary() });
            return json;
        }
    }
```

I've been looking for a solution for over 8 hours now, can anybody please help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Send back a JSON object with the `success` property set to true. Check this in your success handler on the AJAX call and redirect using javascript ( window.location = indexLink).

Worth noting that if you want to generate the link server-side and you're using the web forms view engine you will need to do something like this to embed a script variable in the page:

```
<%= "<script language=\"javascript\"> var indexLink = \"" + Url.Action("Index") + "\";</script>" %>
```

You can then use `indexLink` in your page.

Comment: Thanks, the idea works! I have actually provided the redirectionlink in the JsonResponse object so it will be determined on the server. A very small violation of the MVC paradigma, but this I can accept. It still looks very clean.

Comment: It is slightly but IMO AJAX shouldn't really be used to control application flow in MVC apps. Equally, the Create view should really redirect off to Index rather than returning HTML.

Comment: Make sure that the javascript redirect uses the `href` property for it to work in all browsers. E.g. `window.location.href = indexLink`